# .htaccess mod-rewrite rule with pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a mod-rewrite rule to handle pagination links on my site.

Right now, without pagination, I am using this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/?$ /category.php?cat_slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm a beginner to .htaccess and mod-rewrite, and am not really sure how to proceed in adding another get variable to the end of this for pagination.

I'd like my url structure to be this:
http://www.mysite.com/category/example/2

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/?$ /category.php?cat_slug=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you need

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]?) /category.php?cat_slug=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think the "?" should be replaced by "+" so it becomes ([0-9]+). That way it will match more than one char.